# php function array return?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I was wondering if there is a way to return an array value from a function that returns an array inline. So if I have a function like:

```
class MyObj
{
    public function myFunction()
    {
         return array('arrayIndex'=>'myValue');
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to do this:

```
$object = new MyObj();
$myValue = $object->myFunction()['arrayIndex']; //but this doesn't work
```

rather than this:

```
 $object = new MyObj();
 $myArray = $object->myFunction();
 $myValue = $myArray['arrayIndex'];
```

Simple question but I just don't know if its possible to reference it in a similar way. So yay or nay?

Comment: Please do your homework before posting a question. You find it in the manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-87

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrade to PHP 5.4 and you can then do [array dereferencing](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html).

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
class MyObj
{
    public function myFunction($index)
    {
        $your_array = array('arrayIndex'=>'myValue');
        return $your_array[$index];
    }
}


f$object = new MyObj();
$myValue = $object->myFunction('arrayUndex');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyObj
{
    public function myFunction()
    {
         return array($one,$two);
    }
}


f$object = new MyObj();
list($first,$second) = $object->myFunction();
```